# Why is Console.log(name); in javascript is blank?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

please consider the below code, I have declared a variable with a reserved JS keyword and I didn't assign it any value. When I try to execute it, I am getting output as shown in the code. Please let me know why I am not getting uncaught exception?
Browser is Chrome : Version 86.0.4240.198 (Official Build) (64-bit)
IDE: VS Code

```
var name;
console.log(name); //output is blank
console.log(typeof name); //string

let func = () => {
  var name;
  console.log(name); //undefined
  console.log(typeof name); //undefined
  var xyz;
  console.log(xyz); //undefined
}
func();
```

Comment: window.name is already declared, its empty string

Answer (score 1):

The top level scope in a browser is the `window` object, and Window objects [have a `name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) that is a string. In the Stack Overflow snippet environment, that name is not blank, as you can see by running the below code.

```js
console.log(name);
```

Within the function `func`, the name `name` doesn't refer to `window.name` anymore, and a variable with no value has the value `undefined`, which is what you're seeing.